# Model evaluation results for logistic regression makes no sense

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, logistic-regression

So, I've been trying to built the simplest logistic regression model using sklearn modules but the evaluation results (f1-score, jaccard score, logloss) are all very off.

Here are some details about the dataset:

```
df = pd.read_csv('loan_train.csv')
df.head()
```

[train set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbIa6.png)

Labels:

```
array(['PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'COLLECTION'], dtype=object)
```

There is a train set (X,y) and a seperate test set (X_test,y_test)

And here is what i tried with the logistic regression:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

LR = LogisticRegression(C=0.005, solver='liblinear',random_state=0).fit(X,y)

yhat_lr=LR.predict(X_test)
f1_lr=f1_score(y_test, yhat_lr, average='weighted') #Logistic Regression F1 Score
print("Logistic Regression f1 score:", f1_lr)


j_lr=jaccard_score(y_test, yhat_lr, pos_label='PAIDOFF') #Logistic Regression Jaccard Score
print("Logistic Regression jaccard score:", j_lr,'\n')

lr_probas = LR.predict_proba(X_test)
ll_lr = log_loss(y_test, lr_probas)
print("Logistic Regression log loss:", ll_lr)
```

And here are the results:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOi2O.png)

I have a very low f1-score and jaccard is zero for some reason. Also I don't think the logloss is correct. Also I have this warning:

[warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ajf.png)

I believe this is a very straightforward problem but I can't find the error. Any help is appreciated.